# Class name doesn't reside within package name (from AccessibilityEvent)

Tags: android, android-event, accessibility, package-name

I am working on an android service that tracks window state changes on a device. Each event is logged, including the reported package name and class name that triggered the event. I noticed that some events have a `className` that doesn't reside within the corresponding `packageName`.

For example, when a user opens up the chrome app, I receive an event where the *package name* is '`com.android.chrome`' but the *class name* is '`org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity`'.

I was under the impression that class names were usually a subset of the package name (i.e. if class `ChromeTabbedActivity` was within the package `com.android.chrome` if would have something like `com.android.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity`).

Does anyone know why I'm seeing this phenomenon and could perhaps explain where my understanding of the relationship between package names and class names is wrong?

Comment: How you extract package name. May be it is one from manifest?

Comment: The package name is passed through to my accessibility service via the AccessibilityEvent object sent whenever the listener gets called.